# Eval not defined in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, eval, ribbon

I tried to use `IRibbonControl` to create some customized ribbons and commands under excel 2013.

To load in the new ribbon (`IRibbonUI`), I use the code below:

```
    Public Sub ribbonDoAction(control As IRibbonControl)
    Dim action As String
    action = Replace(control.Tag, "'", """")
    Eval action
    End Sub
```

Then a compile errors comes with message that `Eval` is not defined under Excel 2013.

What function/method I can use to execute the replace of the ribbon with the new one?

`Evaluate` is not the right one to be used in my case from my understanding.

[image]

Under `QA` tab, I have added two sub-tabs for lock/unlock the sheets. I want to add sub-tabs for each sheet to link to that sheet by clicking the sub-tab.

Comment: `Application.Run` is maybe what you want.  There is no concept of `Eval` in VBA (ie. you cannot execute a string containing random VBA)

Comment: @TimWilliams I change it to ```Run``` and the compile passed. But the new tab does not appear in the ribbon. Not sure what step I missed.

Comment: What is the actual content of `action` ?

Comment: ```action = Replace(control.Tag, "'", """")``` @TimWilliams

Comment: I can see that - I mean what is the actual value of `action`?  `Debug.Print action` gives you what?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry I am not very familiar with VBA. After defining this procedure ```ribbonDoAction```, I don't know how to call it correct in a macro definition. It prompts the argument for ```ribbonDoAction``` is not optional and what I need to input as ```ribbonDoAction```'s argument in a ```Call``` clause?

Comment: I don't really know much about the ribbon, but it would be useful to explain step-wise exactly what it is you're trying to achieve, and what you did to get to this point.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have added a picture to show you the ribbon I am working on and the content I want to added to the ribbon by the VBA code.